# Guage controls going behind other controls

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am using a stack layout control as it is best for an up down approach to data however im having trouble with a control that appears not to what to start where i tell it to.

How do I add padding so that my guage does not show corrupted in behind other controls.

```
<StackLayout Spacing="10">
        <Label x:Name="lblWeightType" Text="Please select weight in Kgs"></Label>
        <Picker x:Name="pickerKgs">

        </Picker>
        <Label x:Name="lblheight" Text="Please select height in cms"></Label>
        <Picker x:Name="pickerHeight">

        </Picker>
        <Frame Padding="20">
        <telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge  x:Name="gaugeBmi" Scale="2">
            <telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Axis>
                <telerikGauges:GaugeLinearAxis Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Step="25" />
            </telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Axis>
            <telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Indicators>
                <telerikGauges:GaugeNeedleIndicator Value="30" />
                <telerikGauges:GaugeShapeIndicator Value="40" />
            </telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Indicators>
            <telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Ranges>
                <telerikGauges:GaugeRangesDefinition>
                    <telerikGauges:GaugeRange From="0" To="75" Color="Green" />
                    <telerikGauges:GaugeGradientRange From="75" To="100">
                        <telerikCommon:RadGradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="75" />
                        <telerikCommon:RadGradientStop Color="Red" Offset="100" />
                    </telerikGauges:GaugeGradientRange>
                </telerikGauges:GaugeRangesDefinition>
            </telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge.Ranges>
        </telerikGauges:RadRadialGauge>
        </Frame>

        <Button x:Name="btnCalcBmi" Clicked="btnCalcBmi_Clicked"></Button>
        <Label x:Name="bmiInfo" ></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

As you can see from the image its not behaving as it should and going behind the other controls I can only persume that is cause the way the control draws on the xamrain canvas.

[image]

Comment: remove `Scale="2"`

Comment: I need the scale 2 as its to small other wise.

Comment: @Jason the scale is used to make the component larger as is to small other wise or should i use the min height requested for that ?